# Headless authentication with Azure AD (user/pass combination)

Tags: asp.net, azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, adal

I'm following the guide and example provided by Microsoft [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/) and I'm able to get the demo working, with the authentication happening in a console app, then making a request to a Web API with the correct token.

I'm looking to use this but the code in the console app would need to move to a Web App. Essentially: external server tries to access secure Web API, providing Azure AD username/password in the `Authentication` header of a HTTPS request. I pick up these credentials in the first insecure Web API, and attempt to authenticate the credentials against AD, obtaining the token. From here, I would then call the `[Authorize]`-protected Web API by making a request with the AD token.

At this point I'm using the same code from the example linked above, simply moving the code in the Console app up into the first insecure Web API controller, but I'm having no luck. I read on [CloudIdentity](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) that "You can only use those flows from a native client. A confidential client, such as a web site, cannot use direct user credentials.". Is this true? If so, is there another way to achieve my aim? I need to use the credentials as it may be likely that more services would use the API in the future, so each of these would need their own credentials to use that could be managed within Azure.

EDIT: In reading more around this, should I actually be aiming to use Client authentication, creating an "Application" within the Azure AD, and providing the client ID to each external service looking to call the API, to then authenticate with that, rather than credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your edit is correct. The [Resource Owner Password Credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3) is meant to authenticate users, not applications. Typical use would be from an application that prompts you for username and password and then retrieves a token from Azure AD.

You can use the [Client Credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4) to get a token from Azure AD from a confidential client to call an API without user context. This flow requires that you register the application in Azure AD and generate a key (which will be used as the client secret). You can then use the ADAL library to ge a token from AAD as shown [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon/blob/master/TodoListDaemon/Program.cs).

Comment: Perfect - thanks for that. So if I were to separate this example up, what would the external app send into my API, just the Client ID? Or the Client ID and App Secret?

Comment: I should add that I know in the perfect world the external app would do all this and just send the token through, but I can't guarantee the langauge of the external server to be able to use the Azure libraries, so fetching the token needs to happen within the API before then calling the secure API. In this scenario is it just the Client ID they would send?